# Get different views to display different content

Tags: python, django

I am following this guide here [tango with django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/setup.html) and I am reading/copying as best from here [tutorial part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/)

But I cannot get different views to display different content. I am missing the explanation somewhere/somehow.

so this is my project urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Sayth.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^Sayth/', include('Sayth.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
    url(r'^rango/about/', include('rango.urls')),
)
```

This is my application urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
            url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
            url(r'^$', views.about, name='about'),
            )
```

These are my views

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says Hello World! <a href='/rango/about'>About</a>" )

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("This is the about page. <a href='/rango/'>Index</a>")
```

Both my pages resolve but both show the index page, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The urls defined are not correct. The root urls.py should have only a pointer to the app, and the app's urls.py should resolve the different endpoints.

Try the following urls.py:

```
#Project urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Sayth.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^Sayth/', include('Sayth.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
)


#rango/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
            url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
            url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
            )
```

Comment: Then I get the error Using the URLconf defined in Sayth.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^rango/ ^$ [name='index']
^rango/ ^about$ [name='about']
The current URL, rango/about/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Edited the answer to include the trailing slash. Please try now.

Answer (score 1):

As the first answer have mentioned, your project's urls.py only needs one pointer to the application urls.py.

Conceptually it is like this, anything matching '^rango/' should be passed onto the application urls.py, and then the applications handles the rest of the url.. either '/' or 'about/'

So in your applications urls.py, you then need to ensure that a mapping for each of these patterns exists.

In the tangowithdjango book, the about page is an exercise, left for the reader, but if you have future problems you can always inspect the code for the application, for example:

The project urls.py:

https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django/blob/master/tango_with_django_project/tango_with_django_project/urls.py

The application urls.py:

https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django/blob/master/tango_with_django_project/rango/urls.py

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to create an urls.py on the app you can just do the url mapping like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    # most detailed urls comes first.
    url(r'^rango/about/?$', 'rango.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^rango/?$', 'rango.views.index', name='index'),

)
```